# On windows how to change colors on all printed documents

Tags: windows, api, printing, hook, gdi

I would like to change colors on printed documents for color-blind people.

Currently I am hooking startDocPrinter, EndDocPrinter, ... with a pdf virtual printer which use postscript and it works well. I am able to change colors.

But I have several printers from different companies : HP, Canon. Each of them seems to use different printing language. When I click on "print into a file", the file written seems always different : PCL, EMF, PostScript, ...

When I look at printing process it seems that GDI API is generic and not related on which printing device I will use. If I hook GDI function, could I be able to change colors on all my printers ?

Do you have any advices about this ?

Thank you.

Comment: You drew the right conclusions.  Hooking GDI is not practical.  Short from the difficulty, you'd have to hook every program that uses it.

Comment: @HansPassant thx for comment, if I want to hook GDI for all my program, do you know if some hookings limits exists ? maybe number of programs hooked, or number of functions ?

Comment: The limitations are you getting this right, dealing with processes you can't hook because of bitness and security problems and being able to support users who run some weirdo program that crashes because of your code.  Roughly the kind of task that big companies like McAfee or Symantec take on.  It's possible.  I personally immediately uninstall their software, a somewhat likely fate for any such code.